# Inheritance in Java printing null

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a problem with the inheritance of classes.
here is my Java code:

```
public class spaarRekening extends rekening{
    private double rente;
    public double getRente(){
        return rente;
    }
    spaarRekening(String rN, int s, double d){
        super(rN, s);
        rente = d;
    }
    spaarRekening sR = new spaarRekening("456", 999999, 2.5);
}

public static class rekening implements rekeningIF{
    int saldo;
    static String rekeningNummer; 
    rekening(String rN, int s){
        rekeningNummer = rN;
        saldo = s;
    }
    public static String getRekeningNummer(){
        return rekeningNummer;
    }
    public int getSaldo(){
        return saldo;
    }
}
```

I want to let the spaarRekening be printed out by:

```
System.out.printf("Uw rekeningnummer is: %s\n", spaarRekening.getRekeningNummer());
```

But it prints out null.
Why is this?

Thanks.

Comment: Init a static var inside a constructor is most probably a bug. There are rare cases where this might be reasonable. Furthermore your code is very confusing because every Java-Developer thinks about an instance when reading `spaarRekening.getRekeningNummer()`. In fact this is a static call on the type `spaarRekening`. Types start with upper case letter in Java!

Comment: Any particular reason to have `rekeningNummer` as static? Seems very odd, as you'd think that real-world system would have many (possibly unique) rekeningNummers.

Comment: instantiate spaarRekening instance within itself?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `static`. Not until you understand how it works and where it is applicable.

Comment: Not really an answer but +1 because it fits in very well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you never create any object of type `spaarRekening` or `rekening` the variable `rekeningNummer` never gets initialized, because you do intialization inside the constructor.

You most probably want to make your `rekeningNummer` non-static when you initialize it inside the constructor.

When you really want it to be static then you should initialize it in a static way, too. Therefore remove the code from the constructor and initialize it right away when declaring.

```
public class SpaarRekening extends Rekening{
    private double rente;

    SpaarRekening(String rN, int s, double d){
        super(rN, s);
        rente = d;
    }

    public double getRente(){
        return rente;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpaarRekening sR = new SpaarRekening("456", 999999, 2.5d);
            System.out.println(sR.getRekeningNummer());
    }

}

public class Rekening implements RekeningIF{
    protected int saldo;
    protected String rekeningNummer; 

    Rekening(String rN, int s){
        rekeningNummer = rN;
        saldo = s;
    }

    public String getRekeningNummer(){
        return rekeningNummer;
    }

    public int getSaldo(){
        return saldo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `rekeningNummer` is a static variable and of type`Object` and in your code. The variable has not been intialized, hence it printed `null`.

You have to initialize the static variable before using it:

```
public static class Rekening implements RekeningIF{
    int saldo;
    static String rekeningNummer = ""; // initialized to empty String

    Rekening(String rN, int s){
        rekeningNummer = rN;
        saldo = s;
    }

    public static String getRekeningNummer(){
        return rekeningNummer;
    }

    // Provide method for setting value of rekeningNumber
    public static void setRekeningNumber(String number) {
        rekening.rekeningNummer = number;
    }

    public int getSaldo(){
        return saldo;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't he initialize it in the constructor? just like int saldo; isn't initialized with a int saldo = 0;

Comment: @EricRobinson He does initialize in the constructor, but he never calls the constructor. He is calling a static method on the type `spaarRekening`. Very confusing since OP's types start with lowercase letter.

Comment: To be fair, there is this line there `spaarRekening sR = new spaarRekening("456", 999999, 2.5);`. It's a bit misplaced, but gives you an idea.

Comment: oops! My bad, it didn't see that.

Comment: @maksimov the line put within class definition never get called if the class itself isn't get instantiated at some other place, even if the class is instantiated at other place, it gets StackOverflowError.

Comment: @didxga see "it's a bit misplaced" there? 8-)

Comment: @maksimov yeah, I just elaborated the 'misplace' :-)

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize rekeningNummer, and the default value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized the `rekeningNummer`, you may think that the statement  `spaarRekening sR = new spaarRekening("456", 999999, 2.5);`within your`spaarRekening` class will initialize it, but you are putting it within class definition, you are not actually instantiating any `spaarRekening` instance. Remove that statement, and instantiating it at some other places in your code